# typedef NSDictionary* (^block)(NSString *collect_event);

Tags: c#, objective-c

```
typedef NSDictionary* (^block)(NSString *collect_event);
```

I got this statement from some library in Obj-C and now I need to write it in C# version. Can someone advise me on this?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of blocks in objective c, your block would be synonymous with

```
Func<string, Dictionary<object, object>> block;
```

You haven't detailed the actual implementation of the block so I can't help you there, but it would be something like:

```
Func<string, Dictionary<object, object>> block = x => {
    // do something with x and return a dictionary
};

var someValue = block("Foo");
```

Comment: block becomes a type

i tried this and it managed to compiled. But I have yet to use it though.

public delegate NSDictionary block (NSString collect_event);

Comment: OK. Func is a delegate, so what you've got is the same as I suggested. Is your question now solved?